# Posicionar div de forma aleatória ao carregar página

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando fazer com que uma `div` se posicione de forma aleatória ao carregar página.
Pensei no seguinte, fazer com que a `margin-top` e `margin-left` da `div` fossem randômicas ao carregar a página, quando carregar novamente já exibisse outra margem, assim a `div` ia ter posição diferente. Como posso fazer para gerar números aleatórios na `margin`?

Segue o escopo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .bloco{
            background:blue;
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
        }

    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="bloco">

    </div>    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".bloco").css({'margin-top',' ' , 'margin-left', ' '})//<-- colocar aqui margin top e left de forma randomica 
                                                                        //ao carregar pagina
            });     
    </script>   
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Math.random` para fazer isso:

```
$(".bloco").css({
      marginLeft: (Math.random() * 1000),
      marginTop:  (Math.random() * 1000)
})
```

Observação: Coloquei a múltiplicação por 1000, pois `Math.random` gera um número aleatório de `0` a `1`.

Se você quiser considerar colocar os valores de `margin-left` ou `margin-top` dentro dos limites do tamanho da janela, você pode utilizar `Math.min`, para evitar que ultrapasse o tamanho:

Veja:

```
 {
    marginLeft: Math.min($(window).width(), Math.random() * 1000)
    marginTop: Math.min($(window).height(), Math.random() * 1000)
 }
```

Nesse caso, o valor gerado para `margin-left` sempre seria igual ou inferior ao tamanho da janela. Isso porque `Math.min` sempre retorna o menor valor passado por argumento.

Referências:

- [Math.random - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)
- [Math.min - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, deu certo

Answer (score 5):

Podes fazer assim, de maneira a garantir que nunca vai sair do document (body):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  const m_top = Math.floor((Math.random() * $('body').height()) + 1);
  const m_left = Math.floor((Math.random() * $('body').width()) + 1);
  $(".bloco").css({
    'margin-top': m_top+ 'px',
    'margin-left':m_left+ 'px'
  });
});
```

```css
.bloco{
            background:blue;
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bloco">

    </div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta